# Highlight custom plank icon

Tags: plank

I created a custom shortcut to a libreoffice calc spreadsheet to track my Ingress statistics. However, if I click the icon to open the spreadsheet, the libreoffice calc icon is highlighted instead of my custom shortcut. While I understand why this happens and this behaviour makes sense, I would like to have the custom shortcut highlighted in plank. Is this possible, and if so, how?

Here's my custom shortcut:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Ingress Stats
Comment=ingress statistics
Exec=libreoffice --calc --nologo /home/bene/Dokumente/Ingress\ Stats.ods
Icon=/home/bene/Bilder/Icons/ingressbwi.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Game;
Actions=Ingif;

[Desktop Action Ingif]
Name=Create Ingress Gif
Exec=/home/bene/bin/./ingif
```

[image: customhighlight]

Answer (score 1):

Make a symlink to libreoffice and reference that in your .desktop file.

Make a symlink to libreoffice with this command:

```
sudo ln -s /usr/lib/libreoffice/program/soffice.bin /usr/bin/ingressbwi
```

In your .desktop file change the Exec line to:

```
Exec=/usr/bin/ingressbwi --calc --nologo /home/bene/Dokumente/Ingress\ Stats.ods
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't work.  The libreoffice calc icon is still highlighted when I start my spreadsheet via my custom shortcut.

Comment: The libreoffice executable was just a script that launched the actual binary. I've adjusted the symlink above and tested on Freya.

Comment: I'm afraid to tell you that it still didn't work.  The libreoffice calc icon is still highlighted.  But on top of that,  my spreadsheet now opens,  displays the black background and then freezes....

Answer (score 1):

Based on how plank currently detects which program is running, this will always (correctly) determine that the LibreOffice Calc executable is being used. Parameters are not factored in, and it is probable that LireOffice passes of after loading anyway.